# Duplicate row still being added

Tags: mysql

Using this to try and detect if a tweet with the same ID has already been added to the DB (and not add it if it has).

```
INSERT INTO `Tweets` (`TweetID`, `Time`, `UserName`, `UserNameID`,`RealName`, `ProfilePic`, `Tweet`)  
VALUES ('1234567890', 'Fri, 27 Jan 2012 00:29:39 +0000', 'user', '666', 'user', 'http://...' , 'tweet')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `TweetID` = '1234567890';
```

but its still being added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create unique index that covers single `TweetID` field

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_tweets_tweetid ON tweets (tweetid)
```

Personally I'd recommend you to remove `ON DUPLICATE` part and just use `INSERT IGNORE INTO` instead - as long as you don't need anything to be modified in case of duplication

Comment: Where would I put 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX'? Would it be used for every insert? I can't get 'INSERT IGNORE INTO' to work either.

Comment: @daidai: the `create index` just need to be done just once. It is a separate query - perform it in PMA. It creates index and after that everything will work